# Split regex; keep delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I have a text looks like that:

```
This is [!img|http://imageURL] text containing [!img|http://imageURL2] some images in it
```

So now I want to split this string in parts and keep the delimiters.
I already figured out, that this works, to split the string, but it don't keep the delimiters:

```
\[!img\|.*\]
```

And in some other posts I see that I need to add `?<=` to keep the delimiter.
So I connected both, but I get the error message: `Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed`
Here's the full regex throwing this error:

```
(?<=\[!img\|.*\])
```

I expect as result:

```
[This is; [!img|http://imageURL]; text containing; [!img|http://imageURL2]; some images in it]
```

So whats the best way to fix it?

Comment: Yop! I tried that already, but it wont work look at the problem above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String[] splitArray = subject.split("(?<=\\])|(?=\\[!img)");
```

This splits a string if the preceding character is a `]` or if the following characters are `[!img`.

Comment: Yes I use split() to split it :). Should I use a pattern?